# How do I get an rss feed out of a google scholar search?

Tags: rss, yahoo-pipes

I'd like an rss feed from this google scholar search: [Scholar Fish Oil Search](http://scholar.google.com/scholar?as_q=&num=10&btnG=Search+Scholar&as_epq=fish+oil&as_oq=&as_eq=&as_occt=any&as_sauthors=&as_publication=&as_ylo=&as_yhi=&as_allsubj=some&as_subj=bio&as_subj=chm&as_subj=med&hl=en)

I've looked a little bit at yahoo pipes, and I thought I had found a solution when I found this pipe: [Old Pipe](http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/pipe.info?_id=gqzairKt3BGTuYwHGsevXg) But it doesn't work (it's a couple years old now). If someone can either tell me what's wrong with that pipe, or tell me how to retrieve a feed from that search through another means, I'd be very appreciative.

Thanks for your time,

-Landon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try a 3rd party website that creates feeds from other websites. See [7 Tools To Make An RSS Feed Of Any Website](http://profy.com/2007/09/30/7-tools-to-make-an-rss-feed-of-any-website/). (*Disclaimer*: I have no idea if they work or are any good, but they may be worth investigating).

Answer (score 0):

**[Edit: Google disallows indexing of this content via their robots.txt file, apparently. Check out http://scholar.google.com/robots.txt. Yahoo Pipes respects the robots.txt file—perhaps one of the other tools doesn't suffer from this snag?]**

It appears that markup may have been altered slightly since the publication of this Pipe.

When I use the URL builder module in Pipes and populate the sample query with "fish oil", I get the following search string:
`http://scholar.google.com/scholar?scoring=r&q=%22fish+oil%22&lr=&hl=en&as_ylo=2007`

(Which, when entered into a browser window, does generate results.)

I am currently parsing through their regular expressions to make sure the proper elements are captured.

Did you have any luck with the tools Dan mentioned? Would also be quite interested if any were simple, effective, and (ideally) non-proprietary or self-hostable.